# Gmail API Nodejs and PM2 authentication

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api, pm2

I have set up code to send emails using Gmail API in Nodejs. It works perfectly well in local machine. It asks to enter a code by visiting URL. Something like,

```
Authorize this app by visiting this URL: someURL
Enter the code from that page here: copy-paste code here
```

This is automatically done by Google following [Node.js Quickstart for Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) and it automatically generates `token.json`. Everything works perfectly fine in development.

Now in production, I deploy my app using PM2 and Nginx. So, now each node server is running in background and logs are generated in files.

I see the above prompt in the log file `Enter the code from that page here:`. But as the log is piped to the file, I have no way of pasting the code since I don't have access to standard input.

I have tried generating `token.json` from local and using it in the server which doesn't seem to work.

How do I fix this and is there any way around this?

NOTE: The code to authorize and send mails works just fine. I'm not posting it here because I don't want the question to be cluttered.

Comment: If you are trying to make a server application without need of user interaction instead of using regular OAuth you could try to use [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account). If you insist in authenticating a real user, you can retrieve the `token.json` before implementing PM2 and using it afterwards, I this former not working for you? What do you mean by "from local"?

Comment: I think I'll need to go with the service account. I tried "token.json before implementing PM2 and using it afterwards", it seems to work. But what happens on expiry? By local I mean localhost. Also how to use gmail API with service account?

Comment: If you want to use the Gmail API with service account you will need to use [Domain-Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) so you can impersonate an user in your domain. Also maybe take a look at these links from github [1](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2304) and [2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2968).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. I'll go ahead with this. Could you put this as an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to make a server application without need of user interaction instead of using regular OAuth you could try to use [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).

Although take into account that service accounts don't have the Gmail API per se, so you should enable the [Domain-Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) to impersonate another user of the domain.

If you insist in authenticating a real user, you can retrieve the `token.json` before implementing PM2 and using it afterwards.

Also you can take a look at these two ([1](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2304) and [2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2968)) github posts that also opens your initial thought of trying to use the `stdin` to authenticate the user.