# Google Sheets API authentication using pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-oauth, pm2

I am attempting to set up a node.js project to use the Google Sheets API and run it through pm2.

The app would be used to write to a googlesheet. However, I have yet to find a way to either bypass the authorization prompt or pass in the value to the project running in pm2.

I'm using the following guide to setup the Google Sheets API in the node.js project:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs

From this guide, I've set up my Google Cloud Platform project with the OAuth 2.0 credentials created. Using pm2, I have not found a way to enter the code after following the link for the authorization that is returned in the pm2 logs of the node.js project.

I found a similar post a year back with the issue:
[Gmail API Nodejs and PM2 authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934204/gmail-api-nodejs-and-pm2-authentication)

From this post I set up a Service Account using the following article:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

I then switched from OAuth client in the guide to the google JWT client to use the new service account credentials. However, this returned the same prompt I am unable to respond to in the PM2 logs.

Any advice is appreciated for this project. I think the next option I'm going to try is running the project directly to get the token created per the guide then forcing the app to use it directly.

Comment: please read [ask] then edit your question and include [example]  the code to authorize a service account is not the same as the code to authorize a to a users account.

Comment: Hi DalmTo, thanks for the follow up. I actually got it to work per my answer below. However, I used the exact snippet of code in the guide for the authorization function. In the future I'll post those as well to highlight the code I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Got around this issue by running the project first outside pm2 using the console command "node ." in the project directory per the tutorial guide. I could then enter the authentication code on the terminal prompt.

This created the token I needed for the project. I could then start it in pm2 without issue and use the Google Spreadsheet API.

Didn't need to use a service account, just kept it like the base project in the guide with the credentials it set up.